# Generate a Report On Publication List

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-studio

Can we generate a report on Publication list i.e. how many Persons subscribe or unsubscribe from that particular list in a specific time period ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you would like to know if there is any standard report that can be generated for the publication list.

I would like to inform you that, at present, we do not have a standard report on the publication list at SFMC.

The reason there is no Reporting available for Publication Lists is that they are not actually "Lists", as they do not hold Attribute data as the Lists do, just subscriber identifying information such as Email Address, Subscriber Key is used in the account, and Status. Normal Reports for Lists will not work on a Publication List.

To get data about the information in a Publication list would involve using a Query of the Data View PublicationSubscriber, see our documentation here -

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_publicationsubscriber.htm&type=5

Thanks.